# List comprehension with pandas datetime index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, list-comprehension, typeerror

I'm looking for 6 hour gaps in a pandas dataframe using the datetime index and I want to create a list with the datetime object just after the gap using a list comprehension something like this:

```
starttimes = [x for i, x in enumerate(data.index) if ((x - x[i-1]).seconds/3600.0) > 6 ]
```

but I get the following type error:

```
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object does not support indexing
```

The error occurs after the enumerate(data.index), but I am not sure why I am getting this error because I can do:

```
(data.index[0] - data.index[1]).seconds/3600.0 > 6
```

just fine and the output is true.

I also tried this way and got a different type error:

```
starttime = [x for i, x in enumerate(WaterTest) if ((x.index - x.index[i-1]).seconds/3600.0) > 6 ]

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is there a way to easily do this? I have to use statements like these often in my code and it would be nice to be able to write them in a way similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iteration, the DatetimeIndex converts its values to Timestamps

```
In [26]: index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['20130101 12:00:00','20130101 18:01:01','20130102 9:00:00','20130102 23:00:05'])

In [27]: index
Out[27]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 12:00:00, ..., 2013-01-02 23:00:05]
Length: 4, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [28]: for x in index:
   ....:     print type(x)
   ....:     
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

But there is a much easier way to do what you are doing

Time - shifted_time = timedelta

```
In [29]: td = index.to_series().diff()

In [30]: td
Out[30]: 
2013-01-01 12:00:00        NaT
2013-01-01 18:01:01   06:01:01
2013-01-02 09:00:00   14:58:59
2013-01-02 23:00:05   14:00:05
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This is valid in numpy >= 1.7 (see here for other ops you can do as well as what to do if numpy < 1.7): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas

Differential in 6 hour units

```
In [31]: td.apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(6,'h'))
Out[31]: 
2013-01-01 12:00:00         NaN
2013-01-01 18:01:01    1.002824
2013-01-02 09:00:00    2.497176
2013-01-02 23:00:05    2.333565
dtype: float64
```

Comment: My numpy version is 1.7.1 but I can't use .diff() or .apply on td as you did above do I need to grab a newer version?

Comment: Forgot to import datetime, but its working now and is fast! Thank you